# Is there a module that allows users to post content in steps?

Tags: nodes

sometimes posting a blog post can seem daunting to some of my users. They see a large page with so many entry points that I think I'm missing out on some good content. So what I would like to do is give users the ability to add entries in steps. without seeing the entire form.

1. Title
2. body
3. tags
4. video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Multistep Nodeform](https://www.drupal.org/project/msnf)

> Multistep Nodeform" is a module to split the node creation and node
>   editing form into several steps. This may be usefull for you if you
>   have lots of fields in your content type and would like to provide a
>   wizard-like UI for content creation/editing.